# mysqldump: command not found XAMPP

Tags: shell, xampp

I'm trying to use a script in grunt and node to dump a database.
When I run It return me this error:

```
/bin/sh: mysqldump: command not found
```

I have already contacted the creator of the script and we have understand that the problem is the configuration of my localhost.

I'm using XAMPP 1.8.2-3 in OSX

How can I use correctly `mysqldump`

Thanks

Comment: it seems you haven't specify your `mysqldump` binary path in `.bashrc` or `.profile`.. other way is: you can also can try to execute `./mysqldump` from your `mysql/bin` directory (can't remember to pinpoint the "exact" path, I hope you know it)..

Comment: I added this to my .bashrc /Applications/XAMPP/bin but it doesn't work, inside this directory there is mysqldump @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉

Comment: try to execute: `source ~/.bashrc`, it's to reload the `.bashrc` content again..

Comment: no prob, @WebDesigner..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/bin
```

Then run your script.

So you don't have to do this in the future, check your `.profile` file in your home directory. There should be a line that starts with `export PATH`, something like (only an example):

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Just add your XAMPP path to it:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/XAMPP/bin:$PATH
```

The different directories are separated by colons only, don't add any whitespace.

Comment: Yesterday it was all ok, today I have tried again but it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: For those who don't know where .profile is, it is in the same folder as .bash_profile, namely in /Users/your-user-name/ also available under ~ or $HOME.